# Check if a cell value is in between adjacent cell values in two columns

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I've been working on this problem for a few days and I'd like to see if anyone has any advice or potential work arounds. Here is the question:

I have 4 theoretical columns: ID, Val1, Val2, Val3.  I would like to create a function that checks to see if Val3 lies between adjacent Val1 and Val2 cells and if so, returns the ID for that row.  ID, V1, and V2 have the same number of records.  V3 has significantly more.  Example Below.

```
ID  | V1  | V2 | V3 |  Fx

01  |  11 | 15 | 09 |

02  |  17 | 19 | 10 |

03  |  21 | 25 | 13 | 01

__  | __  | __ | 23 | 03
```

The F(x) would take the first value in V3 and iterate through the V1,V2 array looking for row where:

V1 < V3 < V2 and return the ID for that row.  In V3, the value 13 falls between 11 and 15 from V1 and V2, so it returns the ID value for that row (01).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if multiple rows meet your criteria? Should the function stop at the first row it finds where V1 < V3 < V2 ?

Comment: Also, can you tell us a little of what you've tried? That saves us from going down the wrong path ourselves as well as figuring out your skill level.

Comment: If there are multiple records that meet the criteria, it should ideally find all of them.  I am a pretty new excel user and I've tried mostly the simplest functions (Match, AND, IF, a few nested IFs, etc.)

Comment: If there are multiple matches, how do you want them to be displayed? `01,02`? Your example doesn't include any.

Comment: My solution only returns the first match, not multiple matches. I don't have a quick solution for the multiple match problem, you might need a UDF for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array formula to get the correct result.

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT("a"&MIN(IF((D2<$C$2:$C$25)*(D2>$B$2:$B$25),ROW($B$2:$B$25)))),"")
```

In this formula column B = V1 from above, column C = V2 and column D = V3. The array formula entered in column E = Fx returns the first row where the criteria matches, then uses indirect to get the ID located in column A. The iferror inserts a blank when there is no match which causes the indirect function to error out.

Comment: array formulas need to be written without `{}` curly brackets and entered by pressing ctrl+shift+enter

Comment: Initial testing on this is showing positive.  Thanks for the response.  After I QA it some, I'll come back and confirm.  Thanks!